# Lowering GPU temperature on Radeon 6850 with open source driver

Tags: power-management, radeon, gpu, temperature

I read and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65570/radeon-hd-6950-temperature-is-way-too-hot/181907) and it doesn't work for me!

when I type

```
echo "mid" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

I see what this value really changed (needs the `chmod` was applied before, that is missed in the text), when i type '`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile`'.

But when I check again

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/radeon_pm_info
```

I see no changes! Frequencies are still at max. And yes,

```
/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

is set to 'profile' (not 'dynpm').

How can I change frequencies?! Ubuntu 12.04, Radeon 6850.

Comment: You need to run that command as root, in other words, `sudo -i`, and then `echo "mid" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile`. Run `exit` when done.

Comment: of course I need root! but if I said that profile was really changed, so I've had it. the problem is that it didn't affect gpu frequencies :(