# Cant Change power profile ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ati, power-management, 15.04

I was using following command to change graphics card power profile in Ubuntu 14.10 got from [Radeon HD 6950 temperature is way too hot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65570/radeon-hd-6950-temperature-is-way-too-hot/78540#78540).

```
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

But after installing 15.04 the command failed and error is

```
# echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

- no proprietary drivers installed

How can i change the power profile.

Thanks

Vishnu V

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a permission issue. Try running the command as sudo:

```
sudo echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

Or change the permissions on the power_profile file allowing people to write to this file.

Comment: Its not a permission issue.  I am running the command as root